# Sending screenshot images over network using java sockets

Tags: java, sockets, screenshot

Im working on a sockets program that should : 1/run Server class on some computer, 2/run Client class that is able to connect, disconnect, and then reconnect to the server at any time to receive Server screenshot images.
the problem is that after running Server then client, i could start receiving screenshots, but after a moment i got the error bellow with different stream header @.

I've tried multiple solutions from here and there, but no chance.

Please any help. Thanks.

Server Class:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
class Server {

ServerSocket ssoc;
Socket soc = null;
BufferedImage image;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
ObjectOutputStream oos;

Server()throws Exception {

    ssoc = new ServerSocket(9001);
    System.out.println("Start ...");
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Listening ...");
        soc = ssoc.accept();

        OutputStream os = soc.getOutputStream();
        while(true) {
            try {
                image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new 
Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
                baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ImageIO.write(image,"png",baos);
                baos.flush();
                baos.close();
                oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
                oos.writeObject(baos.size());
                oos.flush();
                os.write(baos.toByteArray()); 
                os.flush();
            } catch(Exception e) { break; }
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String aerg[])throws Exception {
    new Server();
}

}
```

Client Class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class Explorer extends JPanel {

static BufferedImage image;
static Socket soc;
static InputStream is;
ObjectInputStream ois;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos;

Explorer()throws Exception {

    soc = new Socket("192.168.1.212",9001);

    is=soc.getInputStream();
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setContentPane(this);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    while(true) {

        try {
            ois=new ObjectInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
            int size=Integer.parseInt(ois.readObject().toString());
            baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream(size);
            int sizeread=0,bytesin=0;
            byte[] buffer= new byte[1024];
            while(sizeread<size) {
                bytesin=is.read(buffer);
                sizeread+=bytesin;
                baos.write(buffer,0,bytesin);
            }
            baos.close();
            ByteArrayInputStream bais= new 
ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
            image=ImageIO.read(bais);
            this.repaint();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

public static void main(String aerg[])throws Exception {
    new Explorer();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image,0,0,null);
}

}
```

Output:

```
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:866)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:358)
  at client.Explorer.<init>(Explorer.java:42)
  at client.Explorer.main(Explorer.java:65)
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 0BFF0795
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:866)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:358)
  at client.Explorer.<init>(Explorer.java:42)
  at client.Explorer.main(Explorer.java:65)
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 26A9B121
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:866)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:358)
  at client.Explorer.<init>(Explorer.java:42)
  at client.Explorer.main(Explorer.java:65)
```

Comment: Java default serialization has (many issues)[https://www.infoworld.com/article/3275924/oracle-plans-to-dump-risky-java-serialization.html]. Instead, consider a format like JSON, or encodings such as Base64 for large binary data

Comment: Thanks for your comment Thomas , but it seems that i don't know how to implement your solution

Comment: There are quite a few issues with your code, not least the design. However, you are getting the error because the streams (server and client) are being written and read in an un-synchronized manner. In client, you are assuming that at the beginning of each loop there is an object to be read from the stream, where the server may not have written anything yet. I do not hint at any solution because there could be many approaches, not least designing of a proper protocol between the server and the client.

Answer (score 0):

To send and receive data over a network connection, you must have methods to:

- convert your data into a `String` (serialization)
- convert a `String` back into your data (deserialization)

The terms "serialization" and "deserialization" do not specifically refer to the `Serializable` interface, but any technique for converting structured data to and from `String`s.

A popular format is JSON (JavaScript Object Notation). The library Jackson (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) is widely used to do this mapping, and is very powerful and flexible, while remaining simple to use in simple cases.

In the most simple case, you need 3 things:

- A way of representing your data (i.e. a `class`)
- A function that converts to a `String`
- A function that converts back to your data

An example class might look like this:

```
public class ImageMessage {

    private long timeSent;
    private byte[] imageBytes;

    // getters/setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Even if you only needed to use a `byte[]`, it is good practice to wrap this in a class with a meaningful name; A `byte[]` could be anything (an image, an audio file, cryptographic keys, etc), whereas an `ImageMessage` is an `ImageMessage` and nothing else.

Next you need your mapping functions:

```
public static String toJson(ImageMessage message) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();  // from the jackson-databind library, include the maven dependency in your pom
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(message);
}

public static ImageMessage fromJson(String string) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.readValue(string, ImageMessage.class);
}
```

A full class implementing this would look like:

```
public class ImageMessage {

        private long timeSent;
        private byte[] imageBytes;

        public String toJson() throws JsonProcessingException {
            return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(this);
        }

        public static ImageMessage fromJson(String json) throws IOException {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            return mapper.readValue(json, ImageMessage.class);
        }

//        getters and setters


        public long getTimeSent() {
            return timeSent;
        }

        public void setTimeSent(long timeSent) {
            this.timeSent = timeSent;
        }

        public byte[] getImageBytes() {
            return imageBytes;
        }

        public void setImageBytes(byte[] imageBytes) {
            this.imageBytes = imageBytes;
        }
    }
```

From there, you need to be able to read and write these values.

```
Socket socket = ...  // created earlier

PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

ImageMessage toSend = new ImageMessage();  // initialize an object
writer.println(toSend.toJson());  // writes the message to the socket
ImageMessage received = ImageMessage.fromJson(reader.readLine());  // reads the next message from the socket
```

Some notes:

- The above code is **very** fragile. There is no error checking, type checking of json data, etc. It is meant as an illustration of the basic technique for sending data over a `Socket` in a more reliable way than with Java Serialization
- If you plan to use this in anything more serious than a university project, consider using a framework. Reliable servers are hard to write, let the people at Spring or Apache or whoever write it for you. I personally use Spring for a lot of my projects, as it takes a lot of the hard work out of writing networking code (it does all of the above and a lot more for you by default)
- JSON is just one serialization format of many. If you are working with legacy systems, XML might be preferred. YAML is also a viable option (although, in my experience mostly used for static config, rather than messages). Google Protobuf is useful for very constrained systems, but sacrifices some flexibility. In general, JSON is fine for 99% of cases, but switch if you need to.